# How to split a mongodb collection into multiple collection based on a field

Tags: mongodb

I have a single collection in mongo, and I would like to split that collection to multiple collections based on the key/field "source". The "source" value should be the new collection name with documents that are of that source.

```
{
"name": "Name"
"ph": {"phone": "1111"}
"source": "source1"
},
{
"name": "Name Last"
"ph": {"phone": "2121"}
"source": "source2"
}
```

How can I achieve this at mongodb itself?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the below script on `Mongo Shell` to achieve it.

```
var collectionName = "<CollectionName>"
var distinctValues = db.getCollection(collectionName).distinct("source")
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < distinctValues.length; i++) {
    var newCollectionName = collectionName.concat("_".concat(distinctValues[i]))
    db.getCollection(collectionName).aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "source": distinctValues[i]
            }
        },
        {
            "$out": newCollectionName
        }
    ], {
        allowDiskUse: true
    });
    printjson(++count);
}
printjson("DONE!!!")
```