# How can I break up a large collection into multiple smaller collections?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `messages` of 5 million documents which all look like the following:

```
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "612d51a3c08616b5a0709ce2"
    },
    "id": "456834297159413857",
    "guildID": "191202744285204737",
    "channelID": "455814567292902899",
    "cleanContent": "hello world",
    (...other fields)
}
```

I would like to break this collection into different collections with names like `messages_191202744285204737` based on every unique value of the field `guildID`. Is there a way to do this with aggregation? If so, how?

Update: I found this script which worked perfectly :) [How to split a mongodb collection into multiple collection based on a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62481086/how-to-split-a-mongodb-collection-into-multiple-collection-based-on-a-field)

Comment: break in how many collection ?

Comment: Why do you like to do this? Your queries will become more complex and slower.

Comment: The process of 'breaking up' data is generally called as (or part of) _data modelling_ . You need to clearly identify the data, various entities (parts), and the relationships between them. Then there are aspects like how much data and how you are going to access (or query) this data in your application.

Comment: I wanted to break up the data into a collection for each unique value of the field `guildID`. In fact performing this operation sped up my average query time from around 9 seconds to less than 2 seconds in my application.